# Creating more than one entity on SwiftUI

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I am trying to get more than one entity for my coding project at school but I have an error saying invalid redeclaration of data controller.

```
class DataController: ObservableObject{
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Blood Sugar")
    init() {
        container.loadPersistentStores { description, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Core Data failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    



            
        
    }
}

class DataController : ObservableObject{
    let containers = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Carbohydrates")
    init(){
        containers.loadPersistentStores{ description, errors in
            if let errors = errors{
                print("Core data failed to load: \(errors.localizedDescription)")
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: class definitions have to be unique. So rename the second to another name.

Comment: Do you really have several persistent stores or do you really mean entities?

Comment: In future, include a little bit more information such as where you want multiple entities and what 'entities' even is, explain a bit more exact and straightforward objective of your code or at least, what you intend to really achieve

Comment: You are not setting up Core Data Entities in that code. You are trying to set up multiple Core Data persistent stores. To set up multiple entities, you need to edit the  `.xcdatamodeld` which is probably named for the name of you app. See this [Hacking with Swift tutorial](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/how-to-combine-core-data-and-swiftui).

Answer (score -1):

Since you tagged this as SwiftUI, DataController should be a struct. We use value types like structs now to solve a lot of the bugs caused by using objects in UIKit and ObjC. You can see Apple's doc [Choosing Between Structures and Classes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/choosing_between_structures_and_classes) for more info.

If you use an Xcode app template project and check "Use core data" you'll see a `PersistenceController` struct that will demonstrate how to do it correctly. I've included it below:

```
import CoreData

struct PersistenceController {
    static let shared = PersistenceController()

    static var preview: PersistenceController = {
        let result = PersistenceController(inMemory: true)
        let viewContext = result.container.viewContext
        for _ in 0..<10 {
            let newItem = Item(context: viewContext)
            newItem.timestamp = Date()
        }
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nsError = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
        }
        return result
    }()

    let container: NSPersistentContainer

    init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "SearchTest")
        if inMemory {
            container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
        }
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

                /*
                 Typical reasons for an error here include:
                 * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
                 * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
                 * The device is out of space.
                 * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
                 Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
                 */
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
    }
}
```

You can create more entities in the model editor. There is usually only one `NSPersistentContainer` per app. The container can have multiple stores (usually sqlite databases). Then you can assign different entities to each store too. To create an instance of an entity you do that on a NSManagedObjectContext and you can choose which store to save it too, although most of the time people use one store which is the default.